# viewcontroller multiple in uiview storyboard

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I want a master view and view color , view size ( uiviewcontroller ) Separate. Worked uiview color and size Become a heavy application

Explanation image sorry do not speak English

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly you want to create one parent and few child view controllers in the storyboard. You may use container views for it. Here you can see an expample: http://sandmoose.com/post/35714028270/storyboards-with-custom-container-view-controllers

Note: container views are available for iOS 6+

Comment: Thank you ، This is what I want but FirstViewController Size , SecondViewController color , ViewController uitextview

Comment: I want to connect them ؟

Comment: I don't see any problem. See the screenshot: https://www.dropbox.com/s/u33wz6h2mbyclhk/Screen%20Shot%202013-10-18%20at%201.25.08%20PM.png

Comment: He explained the idea more ،، uiviewcontroller1 in itself uitextview ,  uiviewcontroller2 in itself uibutton color red , I want to connect them ؟

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand what do you mean.